# Ошибка не работает бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 67, in <module>
    async def help ( ctx ):
  File "C:\Users\Phlerows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1229, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)
  File "C:\Users\Phlerows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1131, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.
```

Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


PREFIX = '/'

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = PREFIX )

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print( 'Bot Online' )

# Clear message
@client.command( pass_context = True )

async def clear( ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )


#Clear command
@client.command ( pass_context = True )

async def hello( ctx, amount = 1):
    await ctx.channel.purge ( limit = amount )

    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send( f'hello { author.mention }' )
#kick

@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )

async def kick( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    await member.kick( reason = reason )
    await ctx.send(f'У { member.mention } кик, за нарушение правил сервера' )

#Ban
@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )

async def ban( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    await member.ban( reason = reason )
    await ctx.print(f'У { member.mention } бан, за нарушение правил сервера' )
#Unban
@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def unban( ctx, *,member):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        await ctx.guild.unban( user )
        await ctx.print(f'Разбан { member.mention }' )

        return
# Command help
@client.command( )
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )

async def help ( ctx ):
    emb = discord.Ember ( title = 'Навигация по командам' )

    emb.add_field( name = '{}clear'.format( PREFIX ), value = 'Очистка чата' )
    emb.add_field( name = '{}kick'.format( PREFIX ), value = 'Удаление участника с сервера' )
    emb.add_field( name = '{}ban'.format( PREFIX ), value = 'Ограничение доступа к серверу' )
    emb.add_field( name = '{}mute'.format( PREFIX ), value = 'Ограничение доступа к чату' )
    emb.add_field( name = '{}unban'.format( PREFIX ), value = 'Удаление ограничение доступа к серверу' )
    emb.add_field( name = '{}unmute'.format( PREFIX ), value = 'Удаление ограничение доступа к чату' )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )

#mute
@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )

async def mute( ctx, member: discord.Member ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    mute_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Mute' )

    await member.add_roless( mute_role )
    await ctx.print(f'У { member.mention }, ограничение чата, за нарушение прав!' )
#Get token
token = open ( 'token.txt', 'r' ).readline()

client.run (token)
```

Comment: Простите, но нам теперь за вас отлаживать это? В ошибке написано, что не так и на какой именно строке.

Comment: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2141#issuecomment-497649374

Comment: В какой вселенной запостить текст ошибки на SO стало проще, чем вбить его в переводчик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитесь читать консоль! Там все написано.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias
```

Команда уже существует, так произошло потому-что она уже есть по умолчанию.
Если вы хотите удалить команду по умолчанию, то перед объявлением своей функции вставьте `client.remove_command('help')`

Comment: CПАСИБО ОГРОМОНОЕЕЕЕ